# Call variable number of functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Using async.parallel or custom control flow,

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5] //arr could be any length

get_something = function(num, cb){
  async_io(num, function (err, results){
        cb()
  });

}
```

I want to run get_something() on each member of the array in "parallel". When they're all finished I'd like the callback to get called with the results.

Comment: Really in parallel ? Or just the external asynchronous part in parallel ?

Comment: @dystroy Well, at the same time, not truly parallel.

Comment: and does get_something takes a callback and call it ? If not it will be hard...

Comment: @dystroy it can be made to, sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without async :**

```
var n = arr.length, results = new Array(n), oneIsDone = function(index, result){
   results[index] = result;
   if (--n===0) callback(results);
}
arr.forEach(function(val i){ 
    get_something(val, function(result){
       oneIsDone(i, result);
    });
});
```

**With async :**

Using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) supposes your asynchronous function accepts a callback returning an error as first argument and the result as second, just like your final callback :

```
async.parallel(arr, get_something, callback);
```

If your functions don't follow this norm, you'll have to make some ugly wrappings.

Comment: Trying to get the results passed into the `callback` sorted by index. 

`results = [{results from 0}, {results from 1}]`

Similar to how async.parallel works.

Comment: Is result given to the callback you give to get_something ?

Comment: so then get_something should get passed `arr[i]` not `i`? Is `i` the index or the value?